# Can I use docker image ubuntu 14.04 if my host is 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I have **ubuntu 12.04** as main host, can I run *dockerized* **ubuntu 14.04** on it ?

Answer (score 1):

The stock Linux kernel that came with 12.04 didn't have support for the required AUFS file system. Later installs did however install the kernel v3.8 and later, so so you can upgrade and run Docker fine.

```
# install a Docker compatible kernel on Ubuntu 12.04, if it is not already v3.8+
# "uname -r" will tell you the current version running
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score -1):

yes, as you can launch a docker container based on Fedora/Centos/ArchLinux... on your Ubuntu 12.04