# Can Docker image from Ubuntu 14.04 be used on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

If I were to create a docker image with Ubuntu 14.04 as host OS, can I use this docker image on a different machine with Ubuntu 16.04 as host OS?

What about if the image is created on Ubuntu 16.04, can it be used on machine with Ubuntu 14.04?

Update: It seems I should have posted this link before: [Can I use docker image ubuntu 14.04 if my host is 12.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731933/can-i-use-docker-image-ubuntu-14-04-if-my-host-is-12-04)

It seems downvoters are not aware of the corner cases, and hence this unwarranted reaction. Downvoting without explanation is counter-productive and does not help with the learning.

Comment: It is okay if you want to vote down, but kindly leave a comment explaining the problem with the question. I am sure you have every intention of helping by voting down. May I request to take some more time and suggest what to do to avoid your negative vote. Thanks!

Comment: I did not vote down, but if you hover over the downarrow you will see the reasons. "What happened when you tried it?"

Answer (score 1):

Docker solves the problem "works on my machine" as you have heard of.

So that means the host OS could be any if Docker runs over it, you can use your Dockerfile on any OS, it doesn't matter whether it is Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04.

Comment: ...OS can also be Debian, CentOS, Fedora, Mac, Windows... (I know you already said **any**, but just to be clear to the questioner ;-) )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731933/can-i-use-docker-image-ubuntu-14-04-if-my-host-is-12-04 Look at this post. I am not sure about your conclusion.